# Как убрать вывод времени ? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть wpf приложение, в котором выводятся данные. Мне нужно чтобы выводилась только дата, без времени. Как это сделать?

[image: Как это выглядит]

Вот код(xaml):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата рождения">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateBirth}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

(xaml.cs)

```
public partial class ShowUserPage : Page
    {
        public ShowUserPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            people = User.listOfUsers;
        }
        public List<User> people { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Просто задайте `StringFormat` у привязки, должно хватить. Нечто такое: `{Binding DataBirth, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}`, где `dd.MM.yyyy` - формат, либо [сокращение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#ShortDate) (например `StringFormat=d`)

Answer (score 2):

Решение нашлось. Спасибо @EvgeniyZ!

Будет выглядеть так:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата рождения">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateBirth, StringFormat=(dd.mm.yyyy)}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```